# Movie/show where guy buys alien egg and it hatches

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

A space nut buys an egg, then another egg falls to earth. They both hatch and these insect like aliens come out. The aliens attach themselves to the spine of humans to control them and are seeking each other. A girl gets abducted by a different alien species which brainwashes her to hunt down the two insect aliens.

Comment: This is a good start, but you could improve your chances of someone being able to help you by going over this [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)  Can you recall when you watched this, which station perhaps, and edit that information into your question?

Comment: To further what Alith has said the [story id guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) might be of help to you.